# Ownership decorator for multiple object types

Tags: python, django, django-models, decorator, python-decorators

In the Django application I have written, many of the models I have, have an inherent ownership attached. I would like to check this to ensure I am not serving the user anything they should not see.

As such, I adapted the following decorator to check if they own a model:

```
def must_be_yours_question(func):
    def check_and_call(request, *args, **kwargs):
        #user = request.user
        #print user.id
        pk = kwargs["id"]
        Question = Question.objects.get(pk=pk)
        if not (scene.user.id == request.user.id): 
            return HttpResponse("It is not yours ! You are not permitted !",
                        content_type="application/json", status=403)
        return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return check_and_call
```

However, as I have at least 4 different object types where I would like to test ownership, I have had to write 4 different decorators.

Is there a simple way to write one decorator? Would the best way be to pass in an argument?

Comment: I suggest using class based views. This way you can set `model` class variable and use it in your check function using AccessMixin https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/